# Flex mobile: possible to scroll to top of list by clicking status bar?

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, flex-mobile

Is it possible to implement scroll to the top by clicking on the status bar?

I'm thinking of the standard iOS behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Just change the scrollPosition in your view in response to the click or touch event.  Did you attempt anything?  Were you having problems?

Comment: I get the scrolling part, but I can't find any information on if you can receive a event from clicking on the ios status bar (note that I'm not talking about the action bar, but the bar that contains the time and battery status)

Comment: You won't be able to accept events from outside of your application natively.  I suppose it may be possible with the use of Native Extensions, but I'm not sure.  You mention this is standard iOS behavior; can you mention an example?  I was unaware of this behavior.

Comment: Sure, if you go into Settings, scroll down the list and tap on the status bar the Settings list scrolls all the way to the top.

Comment: Wow, after years of using iOS I totally missed that function, not that I find it particularly useful though, as the hit area is rather small thus doesn't work always. Anyway, I agree with Flextras, you can't use it in your Flex app without the use of an ANE.

Comment: It's quite handy if you know about it :) My tiny lady fingers manages to hit the tiny hit area every time ;) Give me a shout if you happen to find a ANE that does the trick. Not sure I wanna try that one by myself..